# Size Of in Java

Tags: java, sizeof

I have downloaded [java.sizeOf](http://sizeof.sourceforge.net/), but I am getting this exception. I am running from eclipse. What should I do?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Instrumentation is null
```

Comment: I think you should add some more details to clarify your question.

Comment: A search on Sourceforge for "sizeof" returned no results.  Have you looked at the project's documentation?  This error sounds like you haven't set up the environment properly.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle: Google found it, so I linked. (Yes, it's documented how to set it up…)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In eclipse, click on 'run as' -> Run Configurations.Go to second tab 'Arguments' and under 'VM arguments' add -javaagent:< path to>/SizeOf.jar

Comment: missing classfile would lead to a ClassNotFoundException, not an IllegalStateException.

Comment: @jwenting I had faced this exception, when i ran sizeOf. So my guess is that qwert too is facing same problem. Since question is not clear i cannot comment more

Comment: +1: In most of these libraries, there is a `premain` method which is called with the Instrumentation object which sets a globally accessible field.  If the library is not loaded as an agent, the `premain` is not called and the field would be `null` If you use the library there is no class missing as its on the classpath.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have added SizeOf.jar in classpath and then configured  export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:SizeOf.jar" in setenv.sh file in Tomcat(7.0.55). Run ps aux | grep tom and found this SizeOf.jar iis there. I am still getting 'Instrumentation is null' exception. Please could you advise on this.

Comment: @Santosh are you sure SizeOf.jar is in the directory where tomcat was run from? I would suggest using the full path to avoid doubt as in this answer.

Comment: export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/home/full/path/SizeOf.jar". Yes, I have used full path. Alos tried export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:/home/full/path/SizeOf.jar" but nothing worked. When I run catalina.sh command from console then I see below line - JAVAGENT: call premain instrumentation for class SizeOf
which means it's loading the class but still getting - Instrumentation is null

Comment: When I added SizeOf.jar in endorsed and lib folder of tomcat & restarted application server then it started working.